# is an alchemy C library faster/slower than an equivalent as3 library?

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, alchemy

I've got a simple question. Suppose some simple lib written on c. Did I understood correctly that alchemy compiles it AS3 before compiling it to swf. If so, will the lib be slower or faster in comparison with the same lib written on AS3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Alchemy](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/) use a [modified actionscript compiler](http://llvm.org/devmtg/2008-08/Petersen_FlashCCompiler.pdf) that allow the use of [new operation](http://ncannasse.fr/blog/adobe_alchemy) who speed up memory access or allow sign extension to deal with C type.

It compile to SWF or SWC format but you have an option to see the as file genereated

Internally Alchemy emulate a processor (it seems to be an X86 proc) and have a library that replicate some of the core C lib such as Malloc, Free, etc...

So you will see a speed gain if your library use memory a lot but otherwise, as it compile to bytecode and emulate the C lib you can see a gain loss.

You will not see in the current state the same speed as your C code.

Comment: Alchemy doesn't emulate an X86 processor.  The C code compiles to as3 bytecode.  However, it *does* emulate the C runtime, with its own memory space and virtual file handles.

Comment: @paleozogt not a full processor but state, register(eax, ebx, ...) stack via ebp, etc...

Comment: so you say some big computations(e.g working with image) will work faster if it's done via Alchemy?

Comment: The big gain is bypassing the internal garbage collector AND the fact that the C/C++ is converted to LLVM IR, and then benefits from LLVM's optimization techniques, finally spitting out AS3 bytecode. So you have a directly accessibly bit of ram for the alchemy portion of your code through ApplicationDomain.domainMemory. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html#domainMemory

Answer (score 1):

No, Alchemy does NOT compile to as3, it functions as a bridge to c/c++ code. So AS3 can utilize the functions written in C/C++ AND thus benefit from the high performance with a minimal degradation. So it will be just a really small fraction slower...

Comment: You're completely wrong. Alchemy uses the C/C++ front end of the LLVM compiler to convert that C/C++ code to LLVM IR, then performs LLVM op on that code, and uses a custom AS3 back end for the LLVM compiler to output actionscript 3 OR actionscript 3 bytecode which is then compiled down by a customized version of the actionscript 3 compiler.